# How to the indexes created in a DB the last 2 months in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have created indexes on my DB the last 2 months. Everything works fine. However, now I have to move those indexes to the UAT ENV. I kept track of the indexes I created. However I want to be sure I didn't miss any. How do I know the indexes created in the last 2 months using a query?

Comment: The biggest issue here is "I didn't keep track of the indexes I created.". This kind of thing is critical for anybody doing technical work. You could do this with a query to find all indexes not in the production list of indexes. But do you have a link server setup between those two servers? The answer to this will decided what the next step is.

Comment: @SeanLange - I don't have a Linked Server. To answer your question more specifically, as a matter of fact I did keep track. I just want to make sure I didn't miss any. As a part of performance optimization, we create a few indexes, drop etc. I just want to make sure I didn't miss any. May be I should have rephrased the question better.

Comment: @SeanLange - I rephrased my question.

Comment: You won't be able to view them by date. But index creation is tracked in the default trace so you can view them in standard reports. But if the buffer got full or the service was restarted they are gone. Your best bet at this point is probably to get a list of indexes in production and bring them into a table on the UAT server. Then do some queries against that list and sys.indexes.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need is to check the indexes in the database through the catalog views. Maybe something like this can help you:

```
SELECT 
     t.name AS TableName,
     ind.name AS IndexName,
     col.name AS ColumnName,
     STATS_DATE(t.object_id,ind.index_id)
FROM sys.indexes ind 
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE STATS_DATE(t.object_id,ind.index_id) > DATEADD(mm,-2,GETDATE())
ORDER BY TableName, IndexName, ColumnName
```

Remember to run in the database you have to check your indexes and not in the master.

Comment: Any creation dates in these DMVs will pertain to the create date of the table the index is on.

Comment: There I edited the query, it should return the date based on the stats of the index. It is not 100 % precise but it is a close one.

Comment: I agree that it could narrow down the list of indexes, but this will return any index where statistics were updated in the last two months, not created

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not maintain index creation information for indexes in a DMV. This is not information you can query.

You can get this information for PK, unique indexes or unique constraints.

See Kendra Little's blog [here](https://www.littlekendra.com/2016/12/13/index-create-and-last-modified-dates-in-sql-server/) for some good info on this topic.

From Kendra's post:

> But if you’re not looking for the create date of a Primary Key, unique index, or unique constraint, you’re out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. There is really no good way to find the indexes created in last two months. The best way is to load the indexes in a table and compare them with DEV Indexes.